# Can I plot a cone about an arbitrary axis in 3D?

Tags: graphics3d

I'm playing around with Mathematica to try to produce a 3D visualization of something. I need to generate the surface of a cone with a circular base. But the axis of the cone must be the body diagonal of a cube, i.e. the vector <1,1,1>. I want the apex angle `theta_a` to be 10.6796 degrees (0.186393 radians). I have no idea if it will prove to be helpful but I am able to generate an arbitrary vector that makes this angle with the body diagonal in the following way. First, I found one such vector by specifying its x and y components and finding a z component that satisfies the appropriate dot product relationship. Then I made a function that rotates a vector about an arbitrary axis by an angle. This function in principle generates the cone that I want if you were to continuously vary the rotation angle between -pi and pi. Here is my code:

```
rotaxis[rotvec_, rotax_, angle_] := 
 Module[{}, (* 
  Rotate a vector rotvec about the vector rotax by radians equal to
angle *)
  vecpar = Dot[rotvec, rotax]/Dot[rotax, rotax]*rotax;
  vecperp = rotvec - vecpar;
  w = Cross[rotax, vecperp];
  vecperprot = 
   Norm[vecperp] (vecperp*Cos[angle]/Norm[vecperp] + 
      w*Sin[angle]/Norm[w]);
  rotated = vecperprot + vecpar
  ]

mvecs = Table[
  rotaxis[{1, 1, 1.46159669020979`}*.6, {1, 1, 1}, q], {q, 0, 
   2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/8}]; 
Graphics3D[{Thick, 
  Line[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}}], Line[{{1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, 1}}], 
  Line[{{-1, 1, -1}, {1, -1, 1}}], Line[{{1, 1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}}], 
  Red, Line[{{0, 0, 0}, mvecs[[#]]}] & /@ Range[Length@mvecs]}, 
 BoxStyle -> {Thick, Dashed}]
```

The function `rotvec` is just taking [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511370/how-to-rotate-one-vector-about-another) and putting it into Mathematica.

The variable `mvecs` is essentially a list of endpoints that would form the base of the cone that I want. The output of the `Graphics3D` shows the whole figure I'm trying to make except I'd like the red lines to replaced by a smooth cone.

Hopefully this isn't a stupid question. I'm woefully unfamiliar with making 3D graphics in Mathematica.

**Edit:** Per a comment from @Jens, this is easily done by using the built-in function `Cone`. The appropriate cone is created by, for example,

```
Cone[{{vec},{0,0,0}},Norm[vec]Tan[0.186393]]
```

where `vec` is the desired coordinate of the middle of the base.

Comment: Why not use  the built-in `Cone`?

Comment: Oh boy. I didn't know that function existed. That makes life very easy. For what its worth the code I pasted above was made to do some other stuff, I didn't come up with it for the sole purpose of generating a cone! Thanks @Jens.

Comment: If you manage to adapt your code, you could simply post the end result as an answer to your own question. It could still be helpful to people. Otherwise, I would suggest closing the question.

Comment: Just edited my submission. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Just to record an answer to the question, here are two possible ways of defining a cone:

```
c1 = Cone[{{1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}, Norm[{1, 1, 1}] Tan[0.186393]];
c2 = {CapForm["Butt"], 
   Tube[{{1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}, {Norm[{1, 1, 1}] Tan[0.186393], 0}]};

Table[
 Graphics3D[{Thick, Line[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}}], 
   Line[{{1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, 1}}], Line[{{-1, 1, -1}, {1, -1, 1}}], 
   Line[{{1, 1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}}], Red, c}, 
  BoxStyle -> {Thick, Dashed}],
 {c, {c1, c2}}]
```

[image: cones]

The obvious choice is to use [`Cone`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cone.html) as shown in `c1`, and an alternative with potentially more flexibility is the method in `c2` which uses uses [`Tube`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tube.html). With `Tube` you can define for example truncated cones by making the smaller radius (in the second argument list of `Tube`) different from `0`.